# Error bootstrapping juju environment maas, crypto/rsa: verification error

Tags: ssh, juju, maas

I bootstrapped the juju environment for maas. It was working fine but, my bootstrapped node formatted due to network boot. I then removed juju and deleted the environments directory and reinstalled juju but not it give error as below. Please help me I'm not able to resolve the issue.

```
2014-09-18 12:12:11 DEBUG juju.mongo open.go:101 TLS handshake failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "juju-generated CA for environment \"maas\"")
2014-09-18 12:12:11 DEBUG juju.mongo open.go:101 TLS handshake failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "juju-generated CA for environment \"maas\"")
2014-09-18 12:12:11 DEBUG juju.mongo open.go:101 TLS handshake failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "juju-generated CA for environment \"maas\"")
2014-09-18 12:12:12 DEBUG juju.mongo open.go:101 TLS handshake failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "juju-generated CA for environment \"maas\"")
2014-09-18 12:12:13 DEBUG juju.mongo open.go:101 TLS handshake failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "juju-generated CA for environment \"maas\"")
2014-09-18 12:12:13 DEBUG juju.mongo open.go:101 TLS handshake failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "juju-generated CA for environment \"maas\"")
2014-09-18 12:12:13 DEBUG juju.mongo open.go:101 TLS handshake failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "juju-generated CA for environment \"maas\"")
2014-09-18 12:12:14 DEBUG juju.mongo open.go:101 TLS handshake failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "juju-generated CA for environment \"maas\"")
2014-09-18 12:12:15 DEBUG juju.mongo open.go:101 TLS handshake failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "juju-generated CA for environment \"maas\"")
2014-09-18 12:12:15 DEBUG juju.mongo open.go:101 TLS handshake failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "juju-generated CA for environment \"maas\"")
2014-09-18 12:12:15 DEBUG juju.mongo open.go:101 TLS handshake failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "juju-generated CA for environment \"maas\"")
2014-09-18 12:12:16 DEBUG juju.mongo open.go:101 TLS handshake failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "juju-generated CA for environment \"maas\"")
2014-09-18 12:12:16 INFO juju.worker.peergrouper initiate.go:71 finished MaybeInitiateMongoServer
2014-09-18 12:12:16 ERROR juju.cmd supercommand.go:323 cannot initiate replica set: can't dial mongo to initiate replicaset: no reachable servers
ERROR bootstrap failed: subprocess encountered error code 1
Stopping instance...
Bootstrap failed, destroying environment
ERROR subprocess encountered error code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've deleted your `$HOME/.juju/` directory, which contains all the SSH keys and certificates juju has generated, without also destroying your juju environment, you won't be able to access the environment from juju anymore, as the credentials and keys are lost.

What I'd recommend is to bootstrap a new environment on your MAAS, using correctly commissioned nodes (in "Ready" state). This way the nodes won't be set to PXE boot and will boot from the local disk instead (e.g. if you reboot them they won't get wiped out but will work as expected).

Comment: I think you are right. By the way I solved it by removing juju-core 1.19 available from ppa juju/stable and installing juju-core 1.18 available from main ubuntu repository. =D Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

So, I re-commissioned all of my servers, cleared out the .juju directory, except for my environments.yaml and I still get "TLS handshake failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "juju-generated CA for environment \"maas\"")".

What more do you have to do to reset things?  Totally wipe the maas server and reinstall?  I get this when I try to bootstrap.  It powers up the commissioned machine without pxe boot and start talking to it, then gets the handshake failed error.

OK, I did a juju destory-environment, re-commissioned my client server, and changed my juju environment name and that seems to have fix this problem.  Now on to the next one.

Comment: What version of juju are you using? Try the latest stable buid.